# Deploying my GWT Application on Tomcat Server

Tags: gwt, tomcat, maven-2

I want to setup a GWT application (Version 2.0.0) with many dependencys in my local Tomcat Server. I started to write a maven2 build script for deploying and packaging of the application.

I wrote a maven2 script which works really fine in my eyes, but I get an error when trying to deploy the out coming war on my tomcat.

`2011-04-21 18:14:13,951 ERROR org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig - Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/quickfinder.ui-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.`

The web.xml is look like the following:
[here](http://pastebin.com/uqf35CB0) and my maven2 script looks like this:
[here](http://pastebin.com/pe5HRiXf)

After compiling and linking and the other stuff my "deploy" directory (named war) looks like:

`|-AnswerPanel.css

|-common.css

|-DomainListPanel.css

|-glossary.css

|-glossary.html

|-images

|-META-INF

|-MulitpleChoiceEditPanel.css

|-MultipleChoiceDisclosurePanel.css

|-NaviPanel.css

|-QuestionnairePanel.css

|-quickfinder

|-Quickfinder.css

|-Quickfinder.html

|-quickfinderportlet

|-QuickfinderPortlet.html

|-styles-css2.css

|-styles-css3.css

|-WEB-INF

|--lib`

Under lib in the WEB-INF directory, all needed library's are available. The Project has got some RPC calls and so on.

With `mvn compile war:war` a .war file and a folder named #artifactId#-SNAPSHOT-1.00 are created under /target.

I don't know how to handle with this error form tomcat, or is there a logical mistake in the pom.xml.

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 1):

Your web.xml is not well-formed: fix the below section

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" [
<!ENTITY GlossaryWebXml SYSTEM "glossary.web.xml"> -->
 ]>
```

Comment: Oh, I have corrected it. But still no change, after recompiling, deploying I get still the same error.

Comment: Did you do a clean build? and checked if the correct web.xml is packaged/deployed

Comment: Yes, I done `mvn clean` and checked the web.xml files in the output directory's, they had all the same content.

Comment: I would say, you need to carefully check the deployed web.xml as it seems failure is because of it not being well-formed

Comment: After formatting the web.xml correct, the problem was, that some of the dependencys I used are exists in a lower version in the mvn repos than the application needs. The application was not written by, I only want to create the buildscript.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add [maven-xml-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) to your `validate` phase. It will check your `web.xml` automatically.